# local project of wamp server won't loaded if we accessed from internet

Tags: wampserver

Anybody here can help me to fix my problem.

I already setup wamp server and we wanted to access from internet the problem is we can access only the main directory of wamp which is www and when we access the project it won't load because it send request to the local ip of the server not the forwarded domain.

Please we need some advice.

Comment: Please show us what you have done to allow access from the internet

Answer (score 0):

Hey!

1. Set up a Private Network for your PC (ex: 192.168.0.111)

2. Forward Ports(NAT Port) on your Router (Port Ex: 5577)

3. You need to register Free DNS

You must make sure to the steps on, edit the correct files below:

**httpd.conf**

> Listen 192.168.0.111:5577  
> Listen [::0]:5577
>   
>   
> ServerName yourDNS:5577
>   
>   
> < Directory />
>     
>   AllowOverride all
>      
>  Require **all granted**
>   
> < /Directory>
>   
>   
> #onlineoffline tag - don't remove
>     
>   Order Allow,Deny
>      
>  Allow from all
>      
>  Require all granted
>   
>   
>  "${INSTALL_DIR}/cgi-bin"
>      
>  AllowOverride all
>         
>   Order Allow,Deny
>      
>  Allow from all
>      
>  Require all granted

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

> VirtualHost *:5577 
>  Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
>       
> AllowOverride All
>       
> Require all granted

4. Go to **[C:/Wamp/alias/]**, change as image of the attached for you:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Rcz.jpg


Done!